# jQuery typeahead with value and name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this typeahead code http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/

But I can't understand the examples.

The server responds with:

```
{
  cities: [{
    id: id
    name: name
  },
  {
    id: id2,
    name: name2
  }]
}
```

This is the js

```
$(function(){
  $.typeahead({
    input: '#hotel-city-autocomplete',
    minLength: 2,
    maxItem: 5,
    order: "asc",
    template: "{{display}} <small style='color:#999;'>{{group}}</small>",
    source: {
      city: {
        ajax: {
          url: '/cities.json',
          path: 'data.cities'
        }
      }
    },
    callback: {
      onResult: function (node, query, result, resultCount) {
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And it doesn't work. How do I fix it to work? I want on the dropdown and input to show the name and to have as value the ID.

Comment: can you post also your HTML please?

Comment: It's trying to fetch `/cities.json` locally so unless you have that on your server you're running the code, the resulting AJAX response will be blank. If you look on the typeahead site, they're hosting the `/cities.json` files and accessing them on the same site.

Comment: No, the request is being made to the backend server, I've tested that.
I just don't know what this script expects next.